# why does my netpay display no answer?

Tags: c

I am writing a code for a payroll check. A function asks the user for hours worked and hourly pay.  Another function accepts hours and rate as arguments and calculates and returns grosspay. Then send grosspay to a function that will calculate and return payrolltax(.22). Then call a function that will accept grosspay and taxes as arguments and return netpay. Last send all data to a function that will display all values (totalhours, hourlyrate, grosspay, tax, and netpay). My netpay is displaying me 0 and tax is displaying wrong answer. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

```
/* Payroll Check */
#include <stdio.h>

float askhoursworked();
float askhourlyrate();
float calculategrosspay(float hours,float rate);
float calculatepayrolltax(float grosspay);
float calculatenetpay(float grosspay,float tax);
float displayallvalues(float ,float ,float,float ,float );

int main()
{
      float hours;
      float rate;
      float grosspay;
      float tax;
      float netpay;
      float values;

      hours=askhoursworked();
      rate= askhourlyrate();

      tax=  calculatepayrolltax( grosspay);
      netpay= calculatenetpay( grosspay,tax);
      grosspay=calculategrosspay( hours,  rate);

      values= displayallvalues( hours, rate, tax, grosspay, netpay);

      return 0;
}


 float askhoursworked()
 { 
       float hours;
       printf("\n Please enter hours worked \t");
       scanf("%f",&hours);

       return hours;
 }

 float askhourlyrate()
 { 
    float rate;
    printf("\n Please enter your payrate \t");
    scanf("%f",&rate);

    return rate; 
 }

float calculategrosspay(float hours,float rate)
{
    float grosspay;
    grosspay=hours*rate;

    return grosspay;
}

float calculatenetpay(float grosspay,float tax)
{
    float netpay;
    netpay=grosspay-tax;

    return netpay;
}

float calculatepayrolltax(float grosspay)
{
    float tax;
    tax=grosspay*.22;

    return tax;
}

float displayallvalues(float hours,float rate,float tax,float grosspay,float netpay)
{
    printf("\n Your total hours are %.2f",hours);
    printf("\n Your hourly rate  %.2f",rate);
    printf("\n Your grosspay is %.2f",grosspay);
    printf("\n Your taxes are %.2f",hours);
    printf("\n Your netpay is %.2f",netpay);
}
```

Comment: Formatting is bad - code cannot be easily read;(

Comment: Do not modify your code to fix the bug after you've received an answer telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Note that you claim that `displayallvalues()` will return a value, but it doesn't.  You never use the variable that the non-existent result is assigned to, but that doesn't prevent the assignment being an error.  The function should be defined to return `void` and the `values` variable should be removed.  Note too that the function `askhoursworked()` should be declared (and preferably defined) with `float askhoursworked(void)` — and `askhourlyrate()` likewise.  As it stands, there is a declaration for those functions but no prototype (C is not C++, where the rules are different).

Answer (score 1):

In C language, Use single pass compiler. That means here, order matters the most.
You are calculating grosspay at last. and you are using it in calculation of netpay and taxes.

Here is the right way..

```
 hours = askhoursworked ();
 rate = askhourlyrate ();
 grosspay = calculategrosspay (hours, rate);
 tax = calculatepayrolltax (grosspay);
 netpay = calculatenetpay (grosspay, tax);
```

Check it on [Online Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/Hye1ZyrqZ)

**EDIT**
  You have also printed your output in wrong manner.

```
  printf ("\n Your total hours are %.2f", hours);
  printf ("\n Your hourly rate  %.2f", rate);
  printf ("\n Your grosspay is %.2f", grosspay);
  printf ("\n Your taxes are %.2f", tax);
  printf ("\n Your netpay is %.2f", netpay);
```

Comment: thank you for putting that in perspective for me I changed my code. One more question can you give me a hint as to why my tax is the same amount as my total hours?

Comment: [michaelj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8595298/michaelj), I have edited my answer, I think you also forgot that. Check my updated answer above.